# Problem on my page with a image on fixed position (Divi builder)

Tags: css, wordpress, css-position, divi

I construct my contact page with the divi builder.
I had no problem until I added the map on the left of the page.
I put it in a fixed position, and obviously it disturbed the whole page. (see screenshot below).
I'm trying to find a solution to block the scroll after my footer so that it goes unnoticed but nothing helps.
By putting an "overflow: hidden" on my body element, for example, the scroll is blocked far too high and does not allow you to see the bottom of the page.
Anyone have a solution for this case?
I thank you in advance.

[capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjDVN.png)

Comment: Try add that map image as a row background and check.

Comment: That was a good idea but we always see the underside of the footer

Comment: That's work! i forget to change th e position in "relative"

Comment: Glad to know. Happy Divi'ing!!